# ES6 Class Attribute Documentation

Tags: javascript, node.js

In javascript functions we can documention like,

```
/**
 * @param {number} x the first number to add 
 * @param {number} y the second number to add
 * @returns total of given 2 numbers
 */
let f = (x, y) => {
    return x + y;
}
```

Is there any standard way or suggestions to document ES6 class attributes (ex.. `this.name`, `this.title`) since any class attributes can be defined in different methods and may get very hard to keep the track.

Comment: [@property](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-property.html) for static props, [@member](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-member.html) for instance props.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Amadan but documentation says `The @property tag is a way to easily document a list of static properties of a class, namespace or other object.`, and i am asking about non static attributes

Comment: Thanks. Can you post this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the comment:

[@property](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-property.html) for static props, [@member](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-member.html) for instance props.